# Multifield and Multikeyword search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Suppose my documents have three fields `message`, `key`, `file_name`. And also suppose I want to find all documents such that:

```
message contains keyword A and B
key contains keyword C
file_name contains keyword D
```

How should I structure my query?  Should I use `query_string` or `match` statement here?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "message": {
                     "query": "keywordA keywordB",
                     "operator": "and"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "key": "keywordC"
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "file_name": "keywordD"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to quickly test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a34cbae154cec7b3cdee2b11232b7631521ff012

Comment: Thanks! This actually helps. Also thank you for the gist